# how to do this in C# a VBA statment

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have to name the excell sheets myself with the patient name which i have in the input file. rather than the sheet1 sheet2 etc.

in VBA:

```
Set wsPatient =ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
wsPatient.Name = "ThePatientName"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can do the same in C# as you did in VBA, VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) provides built in functions to integrate the programming language (VBA) with Excel, However there are lots of libraries that you can use to work with Excel in C#

1. [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439)
2. [COM Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_object) (Excel.Application) [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
if (xlApp != null)
{
    xlApp.Visible = true;
    Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
    Worksheet wsPatient = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.Add(missing, missing, missing, missing);
    wsPatient.Name = "ThePatientName";
}
```

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28VS.80%29.aspx) for details of the references you need to add and the `using` statements.

Once you get past the boiler-plate, the C# code will be pretty much identical to what you are used to with VBA.

Comment: This code is not equivalent to Booksman's VBA code: it creates a new workbook and renames one of its sheets rather than adding a new worksheet to an existing workbook and then naming it ...

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, but like Charles said, you didn't answer the question properly. Something like Worksheet wsPatient = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheet.Add is probably more likely what the person wants.

Comment: @Jon49 OK I hadn't spotted that bit. I thought Charles was complaining about the way I created a workbook rather than using `ThisWorkbook`. Something tells me that the person asking the question wants to do more than the two lines of code presented and in fact the link I gave to the MSDN article is more valuable. Anyway I edited the question. I hope you approve now. By the way you can suggest edits. You will gain reputation if they are accepted.

Comment: Will do in the future, looks good now. Thanks for the advice.